# rust-analyzer on neovim not working on macOS

Tags: macos, rust, neovim, rust-analyzer, nvim-lspconfig

I am using NeoVim with NvChad default configs on a M1 mac. Trying to edit a `.rs` file. Neovim lsp shows snippets but no error or autocompletion.

#### What I did

I have installed `rust-analyzer` with Mason and configured

```
# ~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/configs/lspconfig.lua
local servers=(... "rust_analyzer")
```

That caused Error:

```
[lspconfig] unhandled error: ...ig/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/rust_analyzer.lua:41: Expected value but found T_END at character 1`
```

The problem was empty string was being passed to `line 41: vim.json.decode` that came from here

```
# ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-lspconfig/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/rust_analyzer.lua
   18   local jobid = vim.fn.jobstart(cmd, {
   19   │ on_stdout = function(_, data, _)
-->20   │ │ stdout[#stdout + 1] = table.concat(data, '\n')
   21   │ end,
...
-->41   stdout = vim.json.decode(table.concat(stdout, ''))
   42   return stdout and stdout['workspace_root'] or nil
```

Creating a `Cargo.toml` solved the problem.

But **`Client 1 quit with exit code 1 and signal 0`** was the new error. It means for some reason the `rust-analyzer` crashed! The log

```
# ~/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
[ERROR][2023-05-07 21:37:38] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "rust-analyzer" "stderr"        "error: 'rust-analyzer' is not installed for the toolchain 'stable-aarch64-apple-darwin'"
```

I have installed it though with `Mason` , but does not work. Not even with `:!rust-analyzer` command. Error msg same as the log.

`:!which rust-analyzer` command outputs `~/.cargo/bin/rust-analyzer` should be `~/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/rust-analyzer`. So the package installed with `Mason` is not recognised as it is later it the PATH. (see [this issue](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/issues/1289#issuecomment-1544448868))

#### Conclusion

- Mason installs the correct packages of rust-analyzer for 'stable-aarch64-apple-darwin' toolchain.
- If rustup version of rust-analyzer exists in **~/.cargo/bin/rust-analyzer** it will be used. (this is the buggy package. [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14759#issuecomment-1544562532))
- `rust-analyzer` does not work if `Cargo.toml` is not at **project root**. (according to developers this is expected. see [this reply](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14759#issuecomment-1539720043))

Answer (score 3):

Fix #3 from this list has been merged into branch v2.0
Updating to latest version should fix this issue.

---

3 ways you can solve this issue.

1. Uninstalling `rust-analyzer` from rustup ( rustup installs an unusable version of this package. see [this reply](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14759#issuecomment-1544574240) )

   ```
    mv ~/.cargo/bin/rust-analyzer ~/.backup/rust-analyzer`
   ```

**or**

2. Installing `rust-analyzer` with **homebrew**

   ```
    brew install rust-analyzer
   ```

**or**

3. In your **~/.config/nvim/lua/core/init.lua** file replace **line:61** with `vim.env.PATH = vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/mason/bin" .. (is_windows and "; " or ":") .. vim.env.PATH`. This will add **~/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/** at the beginning of your PATH. (from [issue #1289](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/issues/1289#issuecomment-1549875448) )

   ```lua
   --   ~/.config/nvim/lua/core/init.lua
        59 -- add binaries installed by mason.nvim to path
   ...
   ---> 61 vim.env.PATH = vim.env.PATH .. (is_windows and "; " or ":") .. vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/mason/bin"
   +++> 61 vim.env.PATH = vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/mason/bin" .. (is_windows and "; " or ":") .. vim.env.PATH
   ```

Then add `rust_analyzer` to **lspconfig.lua**.
(
If using **NvChad**, edit **~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/configs/lspconfig.lua** to add `local servers=(... "rust_analyzer")`
)

In work directory make sure project has a Cargo.toml file

```
cargo init
nvim main.rs
```

see [this issue](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/issues/1289#issuecomment-1544448868) to know the problem, also see [this reply](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14759#issuecomment-1539720043)